# Window level events in angular directives are not executing as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

Title may be confusing. Please find the code below:

```
        //html    
    <div id="test1" test></div>
    <div id="test2" test></div>


      //module    
   var myApp = angular.module('app', []);
    
    myApp.directive('test', function () {
    
        return {
            
            link: function (scope,el,attr) {
                
                window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                    console.log("test1");
    
                }
            }
        };
    })
```

I have `window.onbeforeunload` event callback function defined. I have the same directive on two different DOM elements. When `onbeforeunload` event is raised, it is executed only once. I thought it would execute twice so that I can capture the element level info. But this is not happening. It is executing only in the context of element "test1". May be I am doing something wrong. Any inputs please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.onbeforeunload` can only take one event handler function, so each time a new one is assigned, the existing one is removed. One way to get around this is to "append" to the function if there's already one defined (also changed to use `$window` service for better testability)...

```
myApp.directive('test', function ($window) {

    return {

        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            appendOnbeforeunload(function () {
                console.log(el.attr('id'));
            });

            function appendOnbeforeunload(fn) {
                var currentFn = $window.onbeforeunload;
                if (angular.isFunction(currentFn)) {
                    $window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                        currentFn();
                        fn();
                    };
                } else {
                    $window.onbeforeunload = fn;
                }
            }

        }
    };
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw2S8/)